# Is `margin:` and `padding:` supported in iE8-11 ? Issue with iE or CaniUse.com

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Like everyone ive been using `margin:` and `padding:` for years, never had any problems, but i decided to check the caniuse.com tool for some reason and they report that IE dosnt support them. Is this infact correct or an error in caniuse.com ?

[image: screenshot from caniuse]

Comment: I think caniuse.com's search function has a usability problem...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is supported. I think what you are seeing are references to `margin-before` et al. You searched for `margin`, but *CanIUse* gave you this part of the spec.

Note the 'notes' at the bottom of the page. They give hint to this and the title also states *CSS Logical Properties*, which you can read more about here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Logical_Properties.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that result is not what you are waiting to be, feel free to reed this article to notice what is that result talking about:
https://drafts.csswg.org/css-logical-props/

The property that you are trying to check has support in effectively all browsers (since IE6+, Firefox 2+, Chrome 1+ etc). If you scroll down you'll notice that, I know that caniuse can be tricky with more than one result :).

Good luck!